# Nested loops and python programming for sudoku puzzle

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, sudoku

What code can I write for nested loops to print the row, column and number for each non-empty
location in bd.

```
bd = [ [ '1', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '3', '7'],
       [ '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '5', '1', '4', '.'],
       [ '.', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '9'],
       [ '.', '.', '.', '9', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.'],
       [ '.', '.', '4', '1', '.', '3', '7', '.', '.'],
       [ '.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.'],
       [ '4', '3', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '1', '.'],
       [ '.', '1', '7', '5', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.'],
       [ '2', '8', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '6'] ]
```

Output should be

```
(0,0) has 1
```

..and so on for the rest of the bd table

Comment: Please don't go removing your question once you have an answer.  Part of the value of this site is in the questions others have asked (and the answers to them).

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
for row, items in enumerate(bd):
    for col, value in enumerate(items):
        if value != ".":
            print "(%s, %s) has %s" % (row, col, value)
```

prints:

```
(0, 0) has 1
(0, 4) has 2
(0, 7) has 3
(0, 8) has 7
(1, 1) has 6
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: any chance you know my second question i just posted? thanks so much for this one, helped so much